# Can write to csv file but not append

Tags: c#, csv, export-to-csv

```
string pathDesktop = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop);
        string filePath = pathDesktop + "\\mycsvfile.csv";
        string delimter = ",";
        string a = "Enoelpro---[037,033,0,018,030,012,004,021,009,038,035,053,044,050,074,F,018,010,070,000]<Vulpix>[-][037,034,0,022,020,029,002,008,024,036,046,049,041,057,077,F,018,005,070,000]<Vulpix>[-] cual es mejor??";
        List<string[]> test = conv(a,"testrainer");
        int length = test.Count;

        using (TextWriter writer = File.CreateText(filePath))
        {
            for (int index = 0; index < length; index++)
            {
                writer.WriteLine(string.Join(delimter, test[index]));
            }
        }
```

So, at the momement, this works fine, except it doesn't keep the old data in the csv file.  How can I modify this so instead of deleting the data, it simply appends to the data?

Comment: Why can't you use `File.AppendAllText()`?

Comment: The file is being overwritten each time because that is what `CreateText` does.

From https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.createtext(v=vs.110).aspx, 
This method is equivalent to the StreamWriter(String, Boolean) constructor overload with the append parameter set to false. If the file specified by path does not exist, it is created. If the file does exist, its contents are overwritten. Additional threads are permitted to read the file while it is open.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[File.CreateText Method (String)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.createtext(v=vs.110).aspx)

> This method is equivalent to the **[StreamWriter(String, Boolean](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/36b035cb(v=vs.110).aspx))**
>   constructor overload with the **append parameter set to false**. **If the
>   file specified by path does not exist, it is created**. **If the file does
>   exist, its contents are overwritten**. Additional threads are permitted
>   to read the file while it is open.

[StreamWriter Constructor (String, Boolean)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/36b035cb(v=vs.110).aspx)

Here second parameter, true to append data to the file; false to overwrite the file.

If you check the documentation for each method it cleary say the answers for your questions and also there is a suggetion in case of you need to append the file. Use StreamWriter constructor with path and append parameter (true)

Answer (score 2):

Can you please try with [StreamWriter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/36b035cb(v=vs.110).aspx) class?

> If the file exists, it can be either overwritten or appended to. If the file does not exist, this constructor creates a new file.

Instead using 
`TextWriter writer = File.CreateText(filePath)` try to use

`TextWriter writer = new StreamWriter(filePath, true);`

If you pass **true** in constructor it should append text to file.